# PHP append variable to the END of a specific line in file

Tags: php

So I got the following function:

```
function searchWord($fileName, $str) {
    $addthis = “string”;
    $lines = file($fileName);
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
            if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
                    $lines[$lineNumber] = $lines[$lineNumber].$addthis
           file_put_contents($filename, implode($lines) . PHP_EOL);
                    break;
            } else {
                    // do nothing
            }
    }
```

}

It searches for a specific string $str in a file $fileName. It then should add $addthis to the END (!!) of the line $lineNumber the $str was found on.

What the code does now is adding $addthis to the start of the line. I have searched the web but couldn't come up with a satisfying solution to my problem.

Comment: Where does `$test` come from?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be $lines instead of $test. Edited it, though my question has been answered already by hek2mgl!

Comment: @MarijnvanGool: By the way, you don't need `implode()` at all. You can specifically edit one line by copying the array first. See my answer below.

Comment: @Amal Murali: Alright, thanks. Will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the new line character from the end of your line before adding to it, then add a new line character back onto the end of it before writing back to the file. The updated line below should help.

```
$lines[$lineNumber] = trim($lines[$lineNumber]).$addthis.PHP_EOL;
```

Also, the write should happen after the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

In my example, im using a text file called `test.txt` with these 3 lines on it:

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

Here's the PHP code.

```
<?php

// Search Function
function searchWord($fileName, $str, $addThis = 'string') {
    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
        $lines = file($fileName);
        array_walk_recursive($lines, function(&$line) {
            $line = trim($line);
        });
        foreach ($lines as $lineNo => $lineStr) {
            if (false !== strpos($lineStr, $str)) {
                $lines[$lineNo] = $lineStr . $addThis;
                break;
            }
        }
        file_put_contents($fileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
    }
}

// Usage
searchWord('test.txt', 'banana', 'string');

?>
```

After the script is ran, the contents of `test.txt` is:

```
apple
bananastring
cherry
```

is this what you are after?

Comment: The downvote is from my side as it is total non-sense to replace all line endings just to add them again later. Have you heard the word *performance* before?